# Set password with PBKDF2 encryption in kentico 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico, password-encryption

I have to upload around 500 users in the table CMS.User (FirstName, LastName, UserName, Email,UserPassword and UserPasswordFormat) from an Excel sheet.

How to encrypt the password and save it in the database?

```
var newUser = new UserInfo
{
    UserName = userDto.Email,
    UserEnabled = true,
    FirstName = userDto.FirstName,
    LastName = userDto.LastName,
    FullName = userDto.FirstName + " " + userDto.LastName,
    Email = userDto.Email,
    UserPasswordFormat = userDto.UserPasswordFormat,                
    SiteIndependentPrivilegeLevel = CMS.Base.UserPrivilegeLevelEnum.None
};

var newUserSettings = newUser.UserSettings ?? new UserSettingsInfo();

newUser.SetValue("UserPassword", userDto.UserPassword);

newUserSettings.UserPhone = userDto.PhoneNumber;

UserInfoProvider.SetUserInfo(newUser);

UserInfoProvider.AddUserToSite(newUser.UserName, site.SiteName);
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code instead of

```
newUser.SetValue("UserPassword", userDto.UserPassword);
```

you should use:

```
UserInfoProvider.SetUserInfo(newUser); // saves user to DB
UserInfoProvider.SetPassword(newUser, userDto.UserPassword); // saves hashed password
```

Kentico uses CMSHashStringSalt app setting for hashing passwords as well.